# Bundle Identifier

Tags: iphone

my bundle identifier : com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}

app Name : World

my  account name in apple : S111

what's my bundle identifier for insert into itunesConnect for upload app?

company name means "Organization Name" that exist in (Info->build) or means apple id ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your own website and domain name? If you own the registration for the domain sample.com, and your app name is "world", then you would use com.sample.world.  Don't use that because you don't own the domain registration for sample.com.  What domain do you own?

Comment: Then you could use tk.s111.world as your appID.  I sometimes add an additional suffix, such as tk.s111.world01 or tk.s111.world.0, just in case I want to remove an app from sale, and/or do others apps from the same project with very similar names (Free, lite, deluxe, Pro or HD, etc.).